# knexjs use SSH tunnel to connect local to EC2 jump host (connects to RDS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, knex.js, ssh-tunnel

I've been at this for some time. I'm attempting to use `knexjs` and `ssh2`node libraries to connect my `local` to my `RDS` instance via an `EC2` jump host. I am able to connect via `SSH` (in my termal and on dbeaver) into my ec2 instance which talks to my RDS database. I also notice `SSH` works in my code as well but I can't seem to find a way to make knexjs use my ec2 instance to connect, does anyone have any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest method is to **use SSH with Port Forwarding**. You don't say which database you are using, so let's assume port 3306:

```
ssh -i key.pem -L 3333:mydatabase.123456789012.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306 ec2-user@EC2-IP-ADDRESS-OR-DNS-NAME
```

This will forward any requests sent to local port 3333 (you can use any port number) to the EC2 instance, where it will then be forwarded to `mydatabase.123456789012.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306`.

You can then point your SQL client to:

```
localhost:3333
```

That will connect it to the remote database.

Comment: I got it via the port forwarding, thanks so much for pointing me in that directions

Comment: what does `key.pem` contains ? an ssh id_rsa.pub key ?

Comment: The `.pem` file on your own computer would contain the _private_ half of the key. The public half is normally kept in a `.pub` file, and is also kept in the destination computer's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.